# Cross Browser Test With Coded UI Locate Browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I am currently using Coded UI to test on IE and am using the Selenium cross browser components to extend this testing onto Chrome.

Before the most recent update to the dot net bindings from selenium these lines worked fine

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
CurrentBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(onDemandURL);
```

Now I receive the following error stating a null value on the windowHandle

```
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(IntPtr windowHandle)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FromWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControlFactory.FromWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.InitializeTopLevelWindow()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.InitializeCrossBrowserService(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService..ctor(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.BrowserServices.ChromeBrowserService..ctor(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.<.cctor>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.Launch(Uri uri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserFactory.Launch(Uri uri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.LaunchPrivate(Uri uri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Launch>b__14()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.Launch(Uri uri)
```

There seems to be an issue in the CrossBrowserService call to `InitializeTopLevelWindow()`. I'm not sure if that's a bug in the cross browser server or where it's coming from. That being said - is there any other way to launch the chrome browser and assign it to `CurrentBrowser` like I did above, where `CurrentBrowser` is of type `BrowserWindow` in this case. Or am I doing something wrong in the above 2 lines?

Comment: I know Selenium/WebDriver very well, but I've no idea what the code above is doing, nor can I tell anything from that error. Can you edit to add any details or additional logs to help determine whether this is related at all to Sel, or is purely Coded UI.

Comment: Andrew, I'm afraid this looks like the only useful information I could find from my code. I followed this short blog a year or so ago to set this up initially: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/02/05/run-your-coded-ui-tests-against-chrome-using-the-selenium-cross-browser-plugin/

In the blog it basically stated to set BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome"; and then launch the browser to run the tests. None of this code in my source has changed, the only change is the selenium dot net bindings being updated.